# What is the best way to use the insert, delete and update from an Content Provider?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-contentprovider, crud, loader

I am spinning my head around this theme for quite some time. I don't have much experience with Android and I'm trying to code everything using the best approach I can.

I successfuly created a **Content Provider** to wrap my SQLite and some Loaders to query the Data. It works fine, but **I'm having some problems deciding how to insert, delete and update outside of the main Thread**.

I implemented various AsyncTasks to manage these operations and the results seems nice.

**But is this the right approach or am I missing something here?**

**Is there any special class or pattern out there that I never heard of?**

It would be nice if anybody could point me to some direction.
Tks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an `AsyncQueryHandler`. Pretty much exactly what you've done using `AsyncTask`, but all the heavy lifting is already dealt with.

Assuming your Content Provider is all good, basically all you really need to do is (for an update):

```
AsyncQueryHandler handler = new AsyncQueryHandler(ctx.getContentResolver());

final ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
values.put(column, data);

handler.startUpdate(-1, null, uriOfDatabase, cv, selection, selectionArgs);
```

See the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncQueryHandler.html)

Comment: This is great Acco. I'll test it and let you know. Tks

Comment: Tks a lot Acco. It is exactly what I was looking for!